# Python pandas time series compare specific times

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series, normalization

Over and over again in pandas, I find that I have to divide through by a specific time. For example, for each day in a time series, divide each value by the value at 12:00pm.

I feel like this should be a fairly simple operation but I have found no simple solutions.

For example, I want to perform a function on each day in a time series:

```
x = df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(func)
```

For each day, do:

```
def func(df):
    st = df.between_time('10:00','10:00')['y-value']
    end = df.between_time('14:45','14:45')['y-value']
    return (st / end)
```

First, is there any way to say, df.at_time('10:00')? It seems roundabout to write .between_time() here but it works. I've also tried df.index.time but I'm unsure how to say, ==datetime.time(10,0) because that returns a boolean array, not simply the value at 10:00am.

The function doesn't work because, for what I believe is an indexing issue, it spits out N/A at each value and spits out two values for each day (ie. one at 10:00 and 14:45), not one. **This does work if they are the same times, but not if they are different times.** I'm led to believe that arithmetic operations don't work cleanly across different datetimes.

I've also tried:

```
def func(df):
    st = df.reset_index().between_time('10:00','10:00')['mid'].values[0]
    end = df.reset_index().between_time('14:45','14:45')['mid'].values[0]
    return (st / end)
```

And I get an indexing error saying I need to return a DateTimeIndex. I presume that I can't just divide the values through and it will return that value to the respective date, but rather it needs to return some kind of (index, value) pandas object.

Any ideas? Is this a common operation?

Here's what my dataset looks like (use pd.read_clipboard() to read in):

```
                     bid    ask     mid
2000-01-01 12:00:00 288.0   289.5   288.75
2000-01-01 13:30:00 287.8   288.6   288.20000000000005
2000-01-01 14:00:00 287.75  289.25  288.5
2000-01-03 09:30:00 288.5   289.5   289.0
2000-01-03 10:15:00 288.5   289.5   289.0
2000-01-03 10:30:00 289.0   290.0   289.5
2000-01-03 10:45:00 288.75  289.75  289.25
2000-01-03 11:45:00 288.75  289.75  289.25
2000-01-03 13:00:00 288.5   289.5   289.0
2000-01-03 13:15:00 288.5   289.5   289.0
2000-01-03 13:30:00 288.5   289.5   289.0
2000-01-04 09:00:00 281.5   282.25  281.875
2000-01-04 09:15:00 281.0   281.5   281.25
2000-01-04 09:30:00 281.25  281.75  281.5
2000-01-04 09:45:00 281.1   281.85  281.475
2000-01-04 10:00:00 281.7   282.2   281.95
2000-01-04 10:30:00 282.0   282.75  282.375
2000-01-04 10:45:00 282.2   282.95  282.575
2000-01-04 11:15:00 282.3   282.8   282.55
2000-01-04 11:30:00 281.45  282.2   281.825
```

UPDATE: Temporary fix but I'm looking for something cleaner (it's possible it doesn't exist)

```
st_time, end_time = '8:00', '14:45'
st, end = df.at_time(st_time), df.at_time(end_time)
AM = st.merge(end, on='date', how='left').dropna()
AM = AM.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(AM['date']))
AM['AM return'] = (AM[end_time] / AM[st_time]) - 1
AM = AM.rename(columns={'price_x': st_time+' price', 'price_y': end_time+' price'})
```

Comment: show an example of what you are expecting for output

Comment: You don't have a value for 12pm every day, only on the first day.

Comment: try return `(st / end.values)`

Comment: If I don't have 12pm for everyday, can't I just have an N/A for that day? That seems like a natural output.

Comment: What do you get when you run `df.info()`? I copied and ran `df = pd.read_clipboard()` in iPython; for me `df.info` shows MultiIndex instead of DateTimeIndex...

Comment: @measureallthethings I get a DateTimeIndex
@HYRY This seems to work but I can't figure out why and only under very specific cases. Perhaps there can be no N/As in the data? More often than not, I'm getting: `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what I *think* you want.

Reindex the original frame to be all dates in the inclusive range. This makes sure that '12:00' will exist; forward-fill to propogate values.

```
In [66]: y = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min().date(),(df.index.max() + pd.offsets.Day()).date(), closed='left', freq='15T'), method='ffill')

In [67]: y.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 384 entries, 2000-01-01 00:00:00 to 2000-01-04 23:45:00
Freq: 15T
Data columns (total 3 columns):
bid    336 non-null float64
ask    336 non-null float64
mid    336 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3)
memory usage: 12.0 KB
```

divide the new series by the '12:00' values. Note that you have to drop the index (with the .values) here to broadcast it properly. Reindex back to your original frame.

```
In [68]: (y/y.groupby(y.index.date).transform(lambda x: x.at_time('12:00').values)).reindex(df.index)
Out[68]: 
                          bid       ask       mid
2000-01-01 12:00:00  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
2000-01-01 13:30:00  0.999306  0.996891  0.998095
2000-01-01 14:00:00  0.999132  0.999136  0.999134
2000-01-03 09:30:00  0.999134  0.999137  0.999136
2000-01-03 10:15:00  0.999134  0.999137  0.999136
2000-01-03 10:30:00  1.000866  1.000863  1.000864
2000-01-03 10:45:00  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
2000-01-03 11:45:00  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
2000-01-03 13:00:00  0.999134  0.999137  0.999136
2000-01-03 13:15:00  0.999134  0.999137  0.999136
2000-01-03 13:30:00  0.999134  0.999137  0.999136
2000-01-04 09:00:00  1.000178  1.000177  1.000177
2000-01-04 09:15:00  0.998401  0.997519  0.997960
2000-01-04 09:30:00  0.999289  0.998405  0.998847
2000-01-04 09:45:00  0.998756  0.998760  0.998758
2000-01-04 10:00:00  1.000888  1.000000  1.000444
2000-01-04 10:30:00  1.001954  1.001949  1.001952
2000-01-04 10:45:00  1.002665  1.002658  1.002661
2000-01-04 11:15:00  1.003020  1.002126  1.002573
2000-01-04 11:30:00  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
```

This should be robust to your input range and vectorized. However the syntax / ease of use could be improved I think.